# Как правильно спроектировать базу данных mySQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql, backend

Как правильно спроектировать базу данных mySQL? Нужно загрузить данный блок [image]

Я собираюсь создать 2 таблицы, в одной заголовок и текст под ним, в другой список. И связать их по id. Будет ли это правильным решением? Или можно как то в одну таблицу запихнуть?

Comment: Что заголовок, что текст под ним - всё одно текст. А связь - чистое дерево. Достаточно одной таблицы с parent-child.

Comment: А в чём задача-то? Какой практический смысл проектировать что-то сильно сложное? Может, будет рациональнее создать одно текстовое поле и запихнуть в него весь этот html-код?

Comment: Нужно что бы с админки могли редактировать страницу по данному шаблону люди не знакомые с html

Comment: Для этого можно накатить какой-нибудь WYSIWYG-редактор, а с базой мудрить необязательно